# std::string’ has no member named ‘get_name'

Tags: c++

I keep getting this error,

```
  error: ‘std::string’ has no member named ‘get_name’
       cout << name.get_name() << name.get_won() << name.get_lost << endl << endl;
```

even though 'name = name_of_player;' and 'cout << name;' prints the correct name. I am guessing that it is taking the variable and not the actual string? I am not entirely sure, thus I need help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class person {

   string name_;
   int won_;
   int lost_;

   public:
   void set_name(string);
   void set_wl(int,int);
   int get_won() const {return won_;}
   int get_lost() const { return lost_;}
   string get_name() const {return name_;}
};

void person :: set_name(string n) {
   name_ = n;
}

void person :: set_wl(int x, int y) {
   won_ = x; lost_ = y;
}

int number_of_players;
string name;
string name_of_player[31];
int counter;

void get_player()
{
   counter = 1; //Initiating the counter
   cout << endl << "Ok! Now we are going to enter their names in. " << endl;
   for (int i=1; number_of_players >= i; i++)
   {
      cout << "Enter player #" << counter << "'s name... " << endl;
      cout << "The max is 30 players... " << endl;
      getline (cin, name);
      cout << endl;
      cout << "Okay, so player #" << counter << " is " << name << "." << endl;
      cout << "Please press Enter to continue..." << endl;
      cin.ignore();
      name_of_player[counter] = name;
      person name;
      name.set_name(name_of_player[counter]);
      name.set_wl(0,0);
      counter = (counter + 1);
   }

}

void list_players()
{
   counter = 1; //initiating the counter
   cout << "Here are the current players with their respective win/loss ration... " << endl << endl;
   for (int i=1; number_of_players >= i; i++)
   {
      name = name_of_player[counter];
      cout << name.get_name() << name.get_won() << name.get_lost << endl << endl;

      counter = counter +1;
   }
}

int main()
{
   cout << "Welcome to the Chess Tournament Organizer. " << endl;
   cout << "How many people will be playing today? " << endl;
   cin >> number_of_players;
   cin.ignore();
   get_player();
   list_players();
   return (0);
}
```

---

### ******************************************************************************

EDIT: I have solved it and figured it out, past all of my terrible code. The problem was, for every name, I was creating a class of 'person' with that name. But this was bad because it was a local scope. So what I did was change the global string 'name_of_players' to a global variable of the person class with

```
person name_of_player[31];
```

Changing also...

```
cout << "Enter player #" << counter << "'s name... " << endl;
    cout << "The max is 30 players... " << endl;
    getline (cin, name);
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Okay, so player #" << counter << " is " << name << "." << endl;
    cout << "Please press Enter to continue..." << endl;
    cin.ignore();
    name_of_player[counter].set_name(name);
    name_of_player[counter].set_wl(0,0);
```

And doing the same to the 'list_of_players' function.

I am still not completely sure why it didn't work, I wanted several 'person's identified by their names, created by using the name given. So if a user were to input "mike" there would be a person class called mike, and I could find the information of the person class mike, by inputing mike.get_info();

TL;DR
I needed to fix the scope and not run my string as a name of the person class for each person.

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You are confusing between a `person` and the name of the `person`. They are not the same.

Comment: There are a lot of things wrong with your code, you seem to be interchangeably using `string` and `person` at different points, and are using the same variable names for them, and are declaring variables at global scope when they should be declared at a lower scope and passed into functions.

Comment: What are the things that should be declared at a lower scope? Sorry for the terrible code, I just learned how to use classes today. I haven't programmed in a few years.

Comment: @DarrynZartman If possible everything should be scoped. Global variables are sometimes used but for the most part are just a holdover from C compatibility.

Comment: @DarrynZartman From your comments it seems like you understand your mistake. If my answer got you there please accept it by clicking the check mark to the left. Scoping and beautifying the code is probably outside of scope for this question, so instead of editing my answer I've added a link here that primarily uses your code: http://ideone.com/0G8hwz  The linked code does away with global variables and uses a vector instead of a fixed size array.

Comment: Thank you so much, I did the check mark, and I appreciate you taking the time to teach me how to code better!

Comment: @DarrynZartman No problem at all, if you have further questions about my example feel free to link them here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`name_of_player` is defined as an array of 31 `string`s:

```
string name_of_player[31];
```

You get the element from that array enumerated by `counter` when you do:

```
name = name_of_player[counter];
```

So `name` is a `string`. `string`s do not have a `get_name` method.

You may be confused about what `name` is cause you define a local `person name` in `get_player`, but then you never use that locally defined `name`.

---

An ugly way to solve this would be to create another global where you declare `name_of_player` as:

```
person stats_of_player[31];
```

Then at the bottom of the `for`-loop in `get_player` you can assign the locally declared variable to the global array:

```
stats_of_player[counter] = name;
```

You would then be able to use `stats_of_player` in `list_players` instead of your `for`-loop as follows:

```
for (int i=1; number_of_players >= i; i++)
{
    cout << stats_of_player[i].get_name() << stats_of_player[i].get_won() << stats_of_player[i].get_lost() << endl << endl;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I realized that I should just use 'person name_of_player[31];'

Answer (score 0):

name_of_player is array of strings, not person objects. So you trying to call get_name on string object and this is why you are getting such error.

Answer (score 0):

Running your code I get that std::string has no member named get_name, get_won, or get_lost. This is because you are trying to invoke those methods on a c++ string object, which does not have those methods.

Furthermore it seems like you expect name_of_player to be an array of players when it is in fact an array of strings.

Because the methods of your person class are public and not static you need an instance of your person class to invoke those methods (outside of the class definition e.g. main).

```
void get_player() {
  ....
  player p();
  p.set_name("Bob");
  p.get_name();
  ...
}
```